# Can the Django dev server correctly serve SVG?

Tags: python, django, svg

I am trying to serve a svg map using:

```
<object data="map.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="400" height="300">
    <embed src="map.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="400" height="300" />
</object>
```

In Firefox this leads to a plugin prompt. If I rename map.**svg** to map.**xml** it shows the image correctly. I assume this is because the Django's dev server (specifically *django.views.static.serve*) is not serving the svg with the correct mime-type. Is this the problem, and if so, is there a patch?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I don't have Django available to test this at the moment but it looks like the static server uses the [mimetypes library](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/mimetypes.html) to determine the content type (specifically guess_type()).

With a little bit a Googling, I came across [some code](http://moinmo.in/MacroMarket/EmbedObject) that you could probably throw in your settings.py to add support for the svg content type:

```
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type("image/svg+xml", ".svg", True)
mimetypes.add_type("image/svg+xml", ".svgz", True)
```

There's also this [blog post](http://pythonguy.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/content-type-for-pylons-static-content/) specific to Pylons but it mentions a similar issue. He specifies that the MIME types are stored in "/etc/mime.types" and that SVG is missing because it's not an official MIME type. He may be right, since I can't find a MIME-type for SVG anywhere on the [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/).

Comment: That did the trick. Hopefully those get added to mimetypes lib.

Comment: Upvote for solving a strange problem. I had this issue for over a week, django staticfiles seems to serve faux mimetypes in the devserver, like 'image/x-png'. Adding a similar line like above solved that: mimetypes.add_type("image/png", ".png", True)

Comment: I'm not quite sure why, but I just installed [wagtail](http://wagtail.io/) using [generator-wagtail](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-wagtail) and svg logo in admin panel doesn't show. `<img src="/static/wagtailadmin/images/wagtail-logo.svg" alt="Wagtail" width="80">`. I tried the above trick, but calling svg url doesn't seem to have the `image/svg+xml` mimetype applied. I am not serving static files with a server like nginx yet, currently using `'django.contrib.staticfiles',`. Any idea?

Comment: [Here's a more detailed question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540054/why-django-staticfiles-serving-svg-as-application-octet-stream-instead-of-image) for my problem

Comment: Awesome!  Saved me much annoyance in my dev environment!

Comment: This is still the correct solution in django 1.10.5. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you're serving the SVG dynamically from a regular django view, you can specify the mimetype in the [HTTPResponse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) object you return from that view. In this case, you'll want the mimetype in place for both dev and production use:

```
def myview(request):
    svg_data = generate_some_svg_data()
    return HttpResponse(svg_data, mimetype="image/svg+xml")
```

Comment: No the svg is static. So I was hoping Django static serve would take care of it.

Comment: `static.serve` uses python's built-in mimetypes module (as Lance McNearney mentions in his post) to guess the mimetype based on the filename... in my case, it seems to guess correctly (`import mimetypes; print mimetypes.guess_type('map.svg')`. Can you verify using firebug that this is the mimetype being sent with the map.svg file?

Comment: I get (None, None) with Python 2.6 on Windows.

Comment: Interesting! Good to know. On OS X and ubuntu I get 'image/svg+xml' out of the box. Delving into the python source for mimetypes.py, I see that it has a default list of types that does not include svg, and that it has paths to additional type listing helpers for unix-like systems. I never knew this... thanks for your question.

Comment: Also, if you are doing it dynamically, mimetype doesn’t seem to exist (at least on Django 1.7), so I used `content_type="image/svg+xml"` instead

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issuer was the deployment with nginx+gunicorn. My nginx docker image served the text/plain mimetype for .svg file. This extension of mime.types resolved the issue:

```
http {
    include mime.types;
    types {
        image/svg+xml svg;
    }
```