# Django Admin Svg Images Aren't Loading In Development Mode

Tags: django, svg

I'm running Django 1.9 and I am missing several icons on the admin such as the Magnifying Glass for the search box, the Calendar and Clock for `DateTimeFields`. Upon inspecting the element, I see this:

```
<img src="/static/admin/img/search.svg" alt="Search">
```

I checked the file location and my svg files are there. I only have static url set.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Solved the problem using the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312714/can-the-django-dev-server-correctly-serve-svg

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add media urls during development/debug mode.

Add `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to your urls, see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development