# Django 1.9 icone in admin panel not displayed

Tags: python, django, django-admin, favicon

after install django 1.9 my admin panel not displayed icones;

Exemple [image]

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your `settings.py` related to static file serving. Did you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Please update your question to post your configuration details. We cannot help you with a screenshot.

Comment: in django 1.8 work normaly but after update non !!

Comment: Did you configure your webserver to serve static files?

Comment: solved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312714/can-the-django-dev-server-correctly-serve-svg thanks you